# Is Project Reactor a Wrapper around java's CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, project-reactor, completable-future

I want to know if Reactor Types (Mono and Flux) or Even Rxjava Types are a wrapper around Java's Completable Future or are they using their own implementation.

Any Help on the matter will be appreciated

Comment: It is open source, you could read the source and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to know if Reactor Types (Mono and Flux) or Even Rxjava Types are a wrapper around Java's Completable Future

No, they're not a `CompletableFuture` wrapper at all.

RxJava and Reactor are both implementations of the [reactive streams specification](https://www.reactive-streams.org/), created before, but first included with Java 9. This is separate to `CompletableFuture` inrtoduced in Java 8 (which allows you to deal with `Future` in a non-blocking way, but is very limited otherwise when compared to the likes of "proper" reactive frameworks.)

However, note that just because it's not a "wrapper" for `CompletableFuture` doesn't mean that it doesn't integrate with it - `Mono`, for example, has `fromFuture()` and `toFuture()` methods designed to enable exactly this kind of integration, should the use case require it.

Comment: Minor wording issue : the reactive stream specification pre-dates java 9, although this version enabled "built-in" support for it.

Comment: @GPI Fair point. Changed to "included" as I think that's less misleading.